# Unable to update template when new data is added to store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to figure out how to properly perform save using ember data. My models are defined as:

```
AS.AnalyticsRun = DS.Model.extend({
'exerciseId'                : DS.attr('number'),
'exerciseRunId'             : DS.attr('number'),
'queued'                    : DS.attr('boolean'),
'final'                     : DS.attr('boolean'),
'analyticsRunParameters'    : DS.hasMany('analyticsRunParameter')
});


AS.AnalyticsRunParameter = DS.Model.extend({
'name'                  : DS.attr('string'),
'category'              : DS.attr('string'),
'filteredOut'           : DS.attr('boolean', { 'default' : false }),
'equalsDefaultValue'    : function() {
    /* computed property : returns css class name that should be used for the row with parameter having value other than default one*/
    return this.get('value') == this.get('default');
}.property('value', 'default'),
'analyticsRun'          : DS.belongsTo('analyticsRun')
```

});

And in my controller I have a function that performs an insert:

```
 createNewAnalyticsRun : function(createRunFrom, createRunFromId){
    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: AS.baseURL+"analyticsRuns",
        data: {"createFrom": createRunFrom, "id" : createRunFromId, "exerciseId" : AS.Analytics.get('exerciseId'), "exerciseRunId" : AS.Analytics.get('exerciseRunId')},
        success: function(newAnalyticsRun){
            self.get('store').push('analyticsRun', newAnalyticsRun.analyticsRun);
            for(var i = 0, len = newAnalyticsRun.analyticsRunParameters.length; i<len; i++){
                self.get('store').push('analyticsRunParameter', newAnalyticsRun.analyticsRunParameters[i]);
            }
        },
        dataType: "JSON"
    });

}
```

My route looks like:

```
AS.AnalyticsRunsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model : function() {
    var store = this.get('store');
    return store.find('analyticsRun',{'exerciseId':1});
}
```

});

This setup works perfectly(updates my template with added data on save) when my route is setup like:

```
 return store.find('analyticsRun');
```

But with

```
return store.find('analyticsRun',{'exerciseId':1});
```

my template does not get updated upon save even when the added record has exerciseId of 1. When I refresh my page, the newly added data shows up. I am pretty sure that adding filter to the find is causing the issue.

**SOLUTION**: I ended up using jquery ajax call to rest api to get the data in confluence with the solution provide by @sly7_7, like this

```
AS.AnalyticsRunsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model : function() {
    var store = this.get('store'), self = this;

    var exerciseId = //get exercise id from some other logic

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: AS.baseURL+"analyticsRuns",
        data: {"exerciseId" : exerciseId},
        success: function(analyticsRunData){
            for(var i = 0, len = analyticsRunData.analyticsRuns.length; i<len; i++){
                self.get('store').push('analyticsRun', analyticsRunData.analyticsRuns[i]);
            }
            for(i = 0, len = analyticsRunData.analyticsRunParameters.length; i<len; i++){
                self.get('store').push('analyticsRunParameter', analyticsRunData.analyticsRunParameters[i]);
            }
        },
        dataType: "JSON"
    });

    //perfect since I need to return model anyways without calling find
    return store.filter('analyticsRun', function(analyticRun){
        return analyticRun.get('exerciseId') == exerciseId;
    });
},
setupController : function(controller,model){
    this._super(controller,model);
    controller.set('analyticsRunSelectOptions',controller.initAnalyticsRunSelectOptions());
    this.controllerFor('analysisTemplates').set('model',controller.get('store').find('analysisTemplate'));
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use store.filter instead of store.find ? If what you want is filtering and keeping the result as a live array, then filter is the way to go.
In the model hook, I would write something like:

```
AS.AnalyticsRunsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function() {
    store.find('analyticsRun', {exerciseId: 1});
    return store.filter('analyticsRun', function(analyticRun){
      return analyticRun.get('exerciseId') == 1;
    });
  }
```

});

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would need to use find because when I make initial call to a rest API to load data, I need to get filtered subset form the server since the amount would be very high if I fetch all the data in. I am now thinking maybe if I load the json via ajax, and "push" it into the store rather than to do find, thinsg might work. I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes. But thanks again.

Comment: sorry for the delay. In this case, I think you can just use both find and return filter in the model hook. See the updated answer.

Comment: You know what I had tried this earlier and I saw some issues, but now when I try it, it works perfectly. Maybe I just need to clear my cache or something. Thanks again, this works perfectly.

Comment: Np :) I'm glad to help you.